# Why do we divide by a symmetry factor the total cross section of scattering?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, scattering-cross-section

[Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) [Ch. 11 (p.84)](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf#page=98) provides an argument for introducing by hand a symmetry factor $S$ in the final integral for the total cross-section.

$$ \sigma = \frac1{S} \int d\sigma. \tag{11.36} $$

The argument claims that the final state is an *unordered* list of outgoing momenta and since the integral treats it otherwise, we should account for the miscalculation by introducing the symmetry factor by hand.

I don't get it. Could you please illustrate what he means?

Besides, from kindergarten mathematics, I know that $\int df = f$ for any integrable function $f$. Therefore, the argument sounds apologetic and wrong to me.

So, why is the symmetry factor really introduced?

---

### Example:

**Peskin & Schroeder Exercise 4.2 : Decay of a scalar particle**

$$ \mathcal L = \frac12(\partial_\mu \Phi)^2 - \frac12 M^2\Phi^2 +  \frac12(\partial_\mu \phi)^2 - \frac12 m^2\phi^2 - \mu \Phi \phi^2$$

The decay $\Phi \to \phi\phi$ is characterized by the amplitude $\mathcal M = -\color{red}2\mu$. Note the symmetry factor of $\color{red}2$ here in the amplitude already accounts for the multiple identical contractions. The differential decay rate would now be given as

$$ \frac{d\Gamma}{d\Omega} = \frac{\mu^2}{16\pi^2M}\sqrt{1-(\frac{2m}M)^2}\,.$$

Now, to get $\Gamma$ from this, why does everyone divide by a factor of $2$ after integrating over the solid angle?

Answer (score 4):

It is a result of integrating over $d^3p_1d^3p_2$ (momenta of the final-state particles). Such integration counts both
$$\left(\vec p_1,\vec p_2\right)=\left(\vec a, \vec b\right)$$
and
$$\left(\vec p_1,\vec p_2\right)=\left(\vec b, \vec a\right)\;,$$
while these two situations are physically identical if particles $1$ and $2$ are indistinguishable. Hence, to avoid counting the same physical situation twice, you have to divide by 2.

The same works for any set of $n$ identical particles in the final state: you have to divide by $n!$, that is, the number of possible assignments of $n$ different momenta to $n$ indistinguishable particles.

Comment: @Nanashi: are you satisfied with this answer?